# What is the most pythonic way of logging for multiple modules and multiple handlers with specified encoding?

Tags: python, logging, character-encoding, module

I'm looking for concrete advice about how the multiple module and multiple handler logging should be done. I have added my simplified code here, but I don't want to bias the answers - tell me what the best practice is.

I would like to log everything to a file, and warn and above to console.

This is my `level0.py` which I want it to log to the specified file:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from level1 import function1

app = Flask(__name__)

logger = logging.getLogger('logger0')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('../logs/logger0','w','utf-8')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d in %(funcName)s]')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_format)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
console_handler.setFormatter(console_format)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def function0(foo):
    bar = function1(foo)
    logger.debug('function0')
    ...
```

Also, `level1` can be a standalone module, when called as a script. In that case I want it logged to another file. Below is the `level1.py` (has duplicated logging lines):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('level0.level1')

from level2 import function2

def function1(foo):
    bar = function2(foo)
    logger.debug('function1')
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = logging.getLogger('logger0')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('../logs/logger1','w','utf-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d in %(funcName)s]')
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_format)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(console_format)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    bar = function1('foo')
    logger.info('level1 main')
    ...
```

I've copied this logging chunk from `level0`, because I wanted the same logging and it seemed intuitive to put it in main. `level2` is not standalone, so it only has:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('level0.level1.level2')

def function2(foo):
    logger.info('function2')
    ....
```

I started with `logging.basicSetup`, but couldn't set encoding for the file and kept getting `UnicodeEncodeError` when trying to log non-ascii strings:

```
logger.warn(u'foo bar {}'.format(NON_ASCII_STR))
```

(I still get the error as the logger passes the message to its parents)

So, what is the best log design for this case or more generally - multiple modules (with encoding selection - I want utf-8)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For modules consisting of many parts, I use the method recommended in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial), which just has one line per module, `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. As you point out, the module shouldn't know or care how or where its messages are going, it just passes it on to the logger that should have been set up by the main program.

To reduce cut-n-paste depending on which is your main program, make sure your modules have a hierarchy that makes sense, and have just one function somewhere that sets up your logging, which can then be called by any main you wish.

For example, make a logsetup.py:

```
import logging

def configure_log(level=None,name=None):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('../logs/%s' % name,'w','utf-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d in %(funcName)s]')
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_format)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    console_handler.setFormatter(console_format)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

To have your individual modules have a mode in which they behave as main, define a separate function, such as `main`.

In level0.py and/or level1.py:

```
def main():
  # do whatever
```

And in the very top level program, call that function:

```
import logging
from logsetup import configure_log
configure_log(logging.DEBUG,'level0') # or 'level1'
from level0 import main # or level1

if __name__ == "__main__"
  main()
```

You should still have the `__name__ == "__main__"` clause there, some modules (*cough* multiprocessing *cough*) have different behavior depending on whether or not the clause exists.

Comment: I think I understand how things should behave; every module creates a child logger that passes everything to its parent and the top one has the two handlers - so all the records go to the same place. I've created a new `dummy_top_level.py` just like @CaptainMurphy said.

The `level0` logger with two handlers is OK. When I import `level1` functions in `level0`, this creates a `level1` logger whose parent is `root`, not `level0`. This means that I only correctly record stuff from `level0`. Any suggestions?

PS: Thanks @CaptainMurphy, you've helped me understand a bit more about logging.

Comment: Yes, in order for it to work as advertised, your group of modules should ultimately be all under one name, then have submodules within. So, for example, make a folder all_the_levels, put level0.py and level1.py in it, and also make an empty file called __init__.py (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for why). Then do imports like: import all_the_levels.level0. If you want to do from all_the_levels import level0, you'll have to add "import level0" to your __init__.py.

Comment: I've played with it for a while now. I've added `__init__.py` to all folders and moved files around a bit. Package `__init__.py` got the logger configuration. Now I get loggers `level0.level1` and `level0.level2`. Just package hierarchy, not what I wished for, which would be import sequence. Just like you said - I would need a lot of folders to get desired logging, and still it would not be accessible to an outside package. I've come to the conclusion that logging between packages won't work. Am I correct?

Comment: Well, you can always add your handlers to the root logger. I'm not sure what you mean by "between" packages. You can make any functions you want accessible from the top level by adding them to `__init__.py`. From your tippy-top main program, you'll have to configure logging per-package. Can you put your folder hierarchy in the question so I can see how you've arranged it?

Comment: Continuing with those names: I now have a folder/package `level0` with log-config `__init__.py` and all the three modules - `level0.py`, `level1.py`, and `level2.py`. I think I now know what I want :) I'll try something. And thanks, @CaptainMurphy

Comment: Sure. If my answer was helpful consider upvoting or giving the checkmark.

Answer (score 6):

To kinda wrap this up, here is what I did; I've put the following two lines in every module/file:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This sets up the logging, but doesn't add any handlers. I then add handlers to the root logger in the main file I'm running the imported modules therefore pass their records to the root logger and everything gets saved and displayed. I do it like CaptainMurphy suggested, but with `logger = logging.getLogger('')` to work with the root logger

To address encoding - I had problems saving non-ascii strings to file. So I just added `FileHandler` to the root logger, where encoding can be specified. I couldn't do it with `logging.basicConfig`.

Thank you again @CaptainMurphy - I'm sorry I can't upvote you with my low reputation, but I've checkmarked the answer.