# Logging from Multiple Modules to the Same Text File

Tags: python

I've inherited a heap of Python code, that runs a bunch of different processes, but doesn't log anything. I want to set up a good logging process for some of the more important tasks. (I'll set it up for everything eventually.)

The way the code base is set up, there are a bunch of modules that are reused by multiple scripts. What I'd like to do is set the logging up so that messages are logged to stdout, as well as to a text file associated with the script that called it.

From what I've gathered this should be possible, e.g. logging.basicConfig() appears to do almost what I want.

How do I configure my logging so that all the modules log to the same text file, and to stdout at the same time?

Edit: The difference between this, and [What is the most pythonic way of logging for multiple modules and multiple handlers with specified encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005478/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-of-logging-for-multiple-modules-and-multiple-handl) is that I also want to be able to call the modules from different scripts. Possibly at the same time.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005478/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-of-logging-for-multiple-modules-and-multiple-handl

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what I'm doing properly, or at least not being clear.

The way that answer is structured, any calls to functions in that module will always get the logger with the same name. Wouldn't this cause a problem if two scripts were trying to run methods from the same module, at the same time?

Comment: @GreeTreePython: Can you please show the logging configuration code you have tried this far and also demostrate why it doesn't work?

Comment: @GreeTreePython The coding is the same; the complication now comes in how you choose to configure the logging module. You can use a more advanced handler like https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler that will handle your situation.